# Where to add external WCF service in layered Asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, architecture

I am planning to use below architecture (Onion) for a web app.

- App.Core – POCO’s
- App.Data – Repositories using Entity Framework
- App.Service – Business logic layer
- App.Web – Asp.net MVC 5 controllers and views.

Also there are external WCF services to be consumed which accepts data from views/forms and generate the response. 
Now, in which layer these external WCF Services should be included? Should they be part of App.Service layer or use them from the App.Web Controllers?

Comment: What do the services do? If they're executing business level logic then service layer. If they're more concerned with displaying data then you'll probably want them in the web.

Comment: BizTalk orchestration are exposed as WCF services. Views provide data to these services which are then written to the database. They do execute business logic. View models are created based on data required by these services. The idea is to keep the UI and WCF services separate to support testing and not to fat controllers. Also, the way project is going i see more WCF services will be added.

Comment: @chris-crush-code : if the WCF service is executing business level logic then it should reside in App.Service, this is fine. 

But why do you think the service will reside in App.Web when it is more concerned with displaying data ? App.Service should be the normal location, don't you think?

Comment: @Riyaz : Where did you manage to place those WCf services ?

Comment: @Tony it's just a rule of thumb to keep your code organized. Typically there's a 3 tier model: data layer, business (also called service) layer, and the gui. The gui should be concerned with display, business with business logic, and data with the data storage logic. This way you reuse the business logic with other front ends, whether its a web page or web service, you don't have code specific to the page interfering with the web service code.

Comment: I added the WCF services to service layer and accessing the service layer from controller.